# Why is JSON usually recommended over XML in the Google API documentation?

Tags: xml, json

In my app I use multiple Google APIs, and in the documentation of all of them it gives me two options:

- JSON (Recommended)
- XML

Now, when sending requests and retrieving responses why is JSON better? Xcode has a native built in xml parser, and for JSON you must use a JSON parser like AFNetworking. What makes JSON stand out? Is it more efficient or faster?

Comment: http://www.json.org/xml.html wraps up most of my feelings about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is much more efficient than XML, which is larger as a whole than JSON. It is very easy to parse, you can use `NSJSONSerialization` and parse `NSData` representations of JSON in a matter of 2 lines and milliseconds, just shows that it consumes less memory.

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, which is NOT like Java, JavaScript to Java is like ham to hamster. Many people make that mistake.

Answer (score 3):

When you compare the sizes of JSON and XML representations of the same object, JSON is much smaller.

So, when using it to transfer data over a network (like the Internet), it is much more efficient to use JSON.

It is also a simpler standard to implement and use than XML is and is therefore easier to process and parse (meaning less CPU overhead).

For most applications, there is no need for some of the more advanced uses of XML, so JSON is a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is smaller and there is les overhead then with XML.

Yes XML can be parsed by the [`NSXMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but since this is a SAX parser it takes more lines of code to build a good parser.

Als since iOS 5 JSON is als nativily available, [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

`AFNetworking` is not a JSON parser, it will use the native `NSJSONSerialization` if avalalable or else one you supplied.

Answer (score 1):

XML has data types - notably mixed content - that are needed to support free text documents, but which aren't easy to handle in bog-standard programming languages like Javascript. So if you want to use bog-standard programming languages and you don't need to support free text documents, you can avoid the complexity by not using XML. Conversely, if you want to use free text documents, you need XML, and you are best off using a programming language designed to handle it easily, like XSLT, XQuery, or Linq.